# Поиск по массиву (ручной)

Tags: java, массивы

Всех приветствую, у меня такой вопрос, если у меня массив с почти всеми одинаковыми числами, например, 17 и одним каким-то другим, например, c 3, `({17,17,3,17,17,17})` то как мне вывести число которое отличается от всех на экран? Я могу это сделать если знаю конкретное место нахождения числа, которое отличается или числа, которое со всеми одинаковое, но если число будет записано рандомно, то нет..
П.C. Прошу не применять автоматические методы по поиску в массиве, т.к. моя цель научиться правильно делать алгоритмы и думать, а не запускать уже готовое. Любая идея тоже сгодится. Спасибо

Comment: Делаешь сортировку подсчётом, и вместо генерации сортированной последовательности выводишь значение элемента с количеством единица. Например...

Comment: спасибо........

Comment: всего то и нужно, что создать `HashMap[Int, Int]`, куда инкриментить итеративно, а потом найти ключ в мапе, у которого значение равно 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю следующий алгоритм:

```
int повторяется;
int[] nums = {1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1};
if(nums.length <= 2) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
if(nums[0] == nums[1] || nums[0] == nums[2]) {
    повторяется = nums[0];
} else {
    повторяется = nums[1];
}
int index = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if(nums[i] != повторяется) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
if(index == -1) {
    System.err.println("Все элементы массива идентичны");
} else {
    System.out.println("Индекс элемента - " + index);
}
```

Проверку на то, один ли он в массиве, можете добавить сами, введя новую переменную.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Меня вон начали уже заминусовывать, как и твой ответ, "супер-программисты", считающие себя пупом земли..хахах Хотя на английской версии такое редко случается..

Comment: Тоже удивлен. Но это был, наверняка, один человек